# QTWidgets is not defined

Tags: python

Este es mi código. El error aparece en lo que he marcdo en negrita,
GestorInventarioAplicacion=QtWidgets.QWidget, y también en

class GestorInventarioAplicacion(QMainWindow) y en el final

main()

from inspect import ArgInfo

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from PyQt5.QtGui import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget

from gestor_inventario import Ui_GestorInventario

from producto_crear import Ui_ProductoCrear

```
class GestorInventarioAplicacion(QMainWindow):

   def __init__(self):

    super().__init__()

    self.inicializar_gui()


   def inicializar_gui(self):

        self.ui=Ui_GestorInventario()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        #self.ui.mni_producto_registrar.triggered.connect(self.registrar_producto)

        self.show()

   def registrar_producto(self):

        gui=ProductoCrear(self.inventario)

        self.ui.mdi_principal.addSubWindow(gui)

        gui.show()


class ProductoCrear(QWidget):

   def __init__(self):

      super().__init__()

      self.inicializar_gui() 


   def inicializar_gui(self):

      self.ui=Ui_ProductoCrear()

      self.ui.setupUi(self)


   def main():

     app=QApplication(sys.argv)

     **GestorInventarioAplicacion=QtWidgets.QWidget()**

     ventana=GestorInventarioAplicacion()

     ventana.setupUi(GestorInventarioAplicacion)

     sys.exit(app.exec_())


   main()
```

Agradeceré muchísimo vuestra ayuda, porque ya he solucionado varios problemas y parece que sólo me queda este. Muchas gracias.

Comment: podrías probar : GestorInventarioAplicacion= QWidget() dado que ya lo declaraste en los import

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Ahora me da el  Type error: QWidget is not callable.

Comment: bueno, hay varias cosas que estoy adivinando así que voy a descartarlas,por ejemplo  Ui_GestorInventario y Ui_ProductoCrear sin esas importaciones para ejecutar correctamente el script con respecto a ventana solo usaría ventana=GestorInventarioAplicacion() ventana.show()  que ya es un widget¿para que intentar asignarle otro?

Comment: "Comento" las importaciones de Ui_GestorInventario y Ui_ProductoCrear y me da en def inicializar_gui: Ui_GestorInventario is not defined. "Comento" Ui_GestorInventario y recibo en def inicializar self.ui.setupUi(self) "AttributeError: GestorInventarioAplicacion object hs no attribute 'ui'.

Answer (score 0):

Uff, conseguí que funcionara. El programa del que copié el original lo presentaba bastante lioso; ha hecho falta que lo "limpiara" y funciona como debe. Os reiríais del tiempo que me ha llevado algo que ahora se ve tan sencillo. Gracias por la ayuda que se me ha ofrecido. Ya sé que es la primera parte, pero es que ni esto me funcionaba.

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from gestor_inventario import Ui_Gestor_inventario

class GestorInventarioAplicacion(QMainWindow):

```
def __init__(self):

    super().__init__()

    self.inicializar_gui()


def inicializar_gui(self):

    self.ui = Ui_Gestor_inventario()

    self.ui.setupUi(self)


    self.show()
```

def main():

```
app= QApplication(sys.argv)

ventana= GestorInventarioAplicacion()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main()